# What can cause the top row of the iOS number pad to be a different orientation than the rest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation, ipod-touch

The app I'm developing uses a `UINavigationController` to control a variety of `UIViewController`s, some of which are displayed in portrait orientation, and some of which are displayed landscape. Once one of the landscape ones is displayed, if I navigate back through the pages to the root view, part of the keyboard is still displayed landscape:

[image: Part of keyboard is landscape]

...instead of how it should be (and originally is) displayed:

[image]

I've paused the debugger (attached to the iPod) when the root view is loaded after displaying the landscape view, and in lldb, run `po [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation`. It outputs `1`, which is the value for `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait`. So although the device knows it's in portrait mode, part of the keyboard is landscape. I've never seen anything like this before, and am not sure what else to check.

Comment: A `UIKit` bug perhaps?